# Translating the Having Clause from SQL to DAX

Tags: dax

I'm a novice at DAX, I'm trying to translate the below SQL to DAX, but I'm met with some difficulty.

```
Declare @period int = Left (Convert (varchar (8), GETDATE (),112),6)

SELECT

PropertyCode
,

UnitCode
, convert (date,convert(varchar (10), max (period)) +'01') lastoccupied

FROM    G_Space
WHERE rank = 1
and 

Leaseid is not null
and 

period between 201807 and @period
and 

PropertyCode = 30500 

GROUP BY PropertyCode
,UnitCode

HAVING max(period) \< @period

Order by lastoccupied

This is what I tried as a calculated column, but the issue is where to include the Having clause in this.

=

VAR Min_Date = CONVERT ("201807", INTEGER)

VAR CurrentDate = CONVERT (REPLACE (LEFT (FORMAT (TODAY (),"Short Date"),7),5,1,""), INTEGER)

VAR Property_Code = Space \[PropertyCode\]

VAR Unit_Code = Space \[Unit Code\]

VAR Results =

CALCULATE(MAXX(Space,Space\[Period\]),

FILTER (Space, Space \[Period\] \>= Min_Date && Space \[Period\] \<= CurrentDate

&& Space \[PropertyCode\] = Property_Code

&& Space \[Unit Code\] = Unit_Code

&& NOT(ISBLANK(Space\[leaseid\]))

))

RETURN

Results
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this using summarize and MAXX:

=

```
VAR Min_Date = CONVERT("201807",INTEGER)
VAR CurrentDate = CONVERT(REPLACE(LEFT(FORMAT(TODAY(),"Short Date"),7),5,1,""),INTEGER)
VAR Property_Code = Space[PropertyCode]
VAR Unit_Code = Space[Unit Code]

VAR Results =
      MAXX(FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE(Space,
                  Space[PropertyCode],
                  Space[Unit Code],
                  "LastOccupiedDate",CALCULATE(MAX(Space[Period]),
                                           FILTER(Space, Space[Period] >= Min_Date && Space[Period] <= CurrentDate
                                           && Space[PropertyCode] = Property_Code
                                           && Space[Unit Code] = Unit_Code
                                           && NOT(ISBLANK(Space[leaseid]))
                    ))), [LastOccupiedDate] < CurrentDate),
                         [LastOccupiedDate])
RETURN 
      Results
```